# assign specific value to perl STDIN

Tags: perl, stdin

I'm performing a test and need to assign a specific value to STDIN within a perl code.

So instead of reading from stdin like this:

```
#myperl.pl
#!//usr/bin/env perl
#
while (<>) {
print;
}

# echo hello | ./myperl.pl
hello
```

I can just do this:

```
#myperl.pl
#!//usr/bin/env perl
#
<STDIN> = "hello";
while (<>) {
print;
}

./myperl.pl
# hello
```

Of course, the text `hello` can be multiple lines in a real test case scenario.

Comment: no not a duplication. im a beginner in perl and not really sure how to put the suggestion listed in that thread to use in my situation.  can you help?  i just want to assign a value to stdin.

Comment: Yes it is probably not a duplicate. I was not able to read from the string after redefining `STDIN` and then using `<>`, but it works fine if you can change `<>` to `<STDIN>`

Comment: I tried that. it didnt work.  what did you do that it worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`perldoc open`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

> [...] you can open filehandles directly to Perl scalars via:
>
> ```
> open(my $fh, ">", \$variable) || ..
> ```

see also [PerlIO::scalar](https://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO/scalar.html). Further, according to [perldoc perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators):

> The null filehandle <> is special: it can be used to emulate the
>   behavior of `sed` and `awk`, and any other Unix filter program that takes
>   a list of filenames, doing the same to each line of input from all of
>   them. Input from `<>` comes either from standard input, or from each
>   file listed on the command line. Here's how it works: the first time
>   `<>` is evaluated, the `@ARGV` array is checked, and if it is empty, `$ARGV[0]` 
>   is set to `"-"` , which when opened gives you standard input. The `@ARGV` 
>   array is then processed as a list of filenames.

So when you do `while (<>)` it will try to "open standard input" (provided you did not give command line arguments, i.e. `@ARGV` is empty). This `open` command is not affected by the current value of the variable `STDIN`, instead (I guess) it will simply do something like:

```
open ARGV, '/dev/tty' or die "open: /dev/tty: $!";
```

So it seems it is not possible to redefine the behavior of `<>` to read from a string by changing `STDIN`.

But instead of using the null file handle `<>` in your loop, if you could use `<STDIN>` instead.. then redefining `STDIN` to a string file handle would work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "hello\n";
open my $fh, "<", \$str or die "Could not open string file handle: $!";
{
    local *STDIN = $fh;
    while (<STDIN>) {
        print;
    }
}
close $fh;
my $line = <STDIN>;
print "Terminal input: ", $line;
```

**Edit**:

The following also seems to work:

```
local *ARGV = $fh;
while (<>) {
    print;
}
```

Comment: this might be the answer. but Im wondering how do i apply this to the scenario in my original post?  where im assigning a specific value to stdin...i.e. 'hello' ?

Comment: Just set `$str` to the value you want to assign, then `<>` in the `while` loop will pick it up

Comment: it works. but only prints the first line.  so if i assign a content of multiple lines to `$str` it only prints out the first line.  can it be edited to print out everything as it is stored in `$str`

Comment: Yes you can just set the input record separator to `undef` before reading from the handle. For example: `local $/`, see [perldoc perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for more information. Re: *"it only prints out the first line"* : Maybe you could send me the code you are working on? Then I will check it out.